# How can I allow HTTPS protocol for Java web application

Tags: java, https, ssl-certificate, vaadin

I have a Java web application and one of the modules is using Vaadin for rendering the web interface. This module is running inside a docker container on a server. Could anyone help me to understand how I can add a SSL certificate in order to allow https calls for this module?

I have an assumption that we need to add the cert in cacerts file in java security directory but I don't have direct access to it since it's inside docker container.

I have tried to add the following line to docker-compose.yml for this module in volumes section.

```
volumes:

${CONF_DIR}/backend/cert/cacerts:/usr/java/default/lib/security/
```

But when I call https://xxxxx... I'm getting the error - This site can’t provide a secure connection ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the Docker server has an ingress or reverse proxy in front of it that handles HTTPS.

But if you need to do it yourself you have to configure Spring Boot:

```
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=<location of the cert>
server.ssl.key-store-password=<password>
server.ssl.key-alias=<the alias>
```

Please find the official guide here: https://spring.io/blog/2023/06/07/securing-spring-boot-applications-with-ssl

Comment: Hi! @Simon Martinelli. The thing is that I don't use Spring Boot configuration in this project. But as far as I understand, we use Jetty embedded web server in the application and we have ptconfig.properties file on the server where we start containers. Jetty configuration refers to ptconfig.properties file

`Properties propsLoad = new Properties();
  propsLoad.load(new FileInputStream("conf/ptconfig.properties"));`

Should I add the above properties to my ptconfig.properties file?

Comment: In that case checkout https://medium.com/vividcode/enable-https-support-with-self-signed-certificate-for-embedded-jetty-9-d3a86f83e9d9